# How to use loop in comment section

Tags: php, xml, foreach, comments

I have used foreach loop to extract multiple value of user_phone between  tab but it will produce error.I dont what is exact formate.

```
 $result = $Admin->select($Admin->newsletter_subscribers,'',"");
 print_r($result['user_phone']);
 $data="<message-submit-request>
 <username>@@@@@@@</username>
 <password>#######</password>
 <sender-id>$$$$$$</sender-id>".
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
   "<to>".$row['user_phone']."</to>"
 }."<MType></MType>
<message-text>
<text>hi test message 1</text>
</message-text>
</message-submit-request>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $Admin->select($Admin->newsletter_subscribers,'',"");
print_r($result['user_phone']);
$data = "<message-submit-request>
 <username>@@@@@@@</username>
 <password>#######</password>
 <sender-id>$$$$$$</sender-id>";

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $data .= "<to>".$row['user_phone']."</to>";
 }

 $data .= "<MType></MType>
<message-text>
<text>hi test message 1</text>
</message-text>
</message-submit-request>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact format for string concatenation is shown in the [PHP manual under *string operators*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). However I won't elaborate on these directly becasue cerating XML by concatenating strings is a bad idea. For example having characters like `<`, `>` and `&` in your input, you'll run into many problems.

For your use-case **SimpleXMLElement** is a handy object that allows you to do the same in a much more consisted manner:

```
// create XML document based on boilerplate
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('
<message-submit-request>
    <username>@@@@@@@</username>
    <password>#######</password>
    <sender-id>$$$$$$</sender-id>
    <MType></MType>
    <message-text>
        <text>hi test message 1</text>
    </message-text>
</message-submit-request>
');

// add elements where appropriate
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $xml->addChild('to', $row['user_phone']);
}
```

This will ensure that all values are properly encoded. Additionally this can have a magnitude on benefits when you further process the data, e.g. outputting it.

However you haven't shown in your question what follows up with `$data` so you need to know how to obtain the XML from the **SimpleXMLElement** as string to make the example complete. Here it is:

```
$data = $xml->asXML();
```

See as well the [SimpleXML *Basic Usage* guide in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) if you'd like to learn more.